# MQTT not connecting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I am currently trying to setup a simple MQTT subscriber using the `paho.mqtt` library...

Something like this

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
hostname = "mqtt://localhost:1883"
client = mqtt.Client(hostname, True, None, mqtt.MQTTv31)
client.connect(hostname)
client.subscribe("hermes/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)

client.on_message=on_message
client.loop_forever()
```

gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bedroom.py", line 5, in <module>
    client.connect(hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Which i don't understand, why is not connecting?
I have similar script in java, which works without any problems?

Comment: I suspect you either have a bad `hostname` or some strange network configuration on your box such that it can't resolve the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Paho python [docs](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#connect-reconnect-disconnect)

> **connect()**
>
> ```
> connect(host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
> ```
>
> The connect() function connects the client to a broker. This is a
>   blocking function. It takes the following arguments:
>
> *host*
>
> the hostname or IP address of the remote broker
>
> *port*
>
> the network port of the server host to connect to. Defaults to 1883. Note that the default port for MQTT over SSL/TLS is 8883 so if you are using tls_set() or tls_set_context(), the port may need
>   providing manually
>
> ...

The `connect()` function takes a hostname or IP address. You have passed it a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). If you remove the `mqtt://` from the start and `:1883` from the of the `hostname` variable it will connect.